# Проблема с кодировкой в вордпрессе

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Всем доброго времени суток. 
Есть некоторые проблемы с кодировкой (не уверен, что проблема именно в этом, отсутствие знаний не позволяет конкретно определить проблему) на сайте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это происходит только тогда, когда я не залогин на сайте. Если я логинюсь на сайте, то эта проблема почему-то пропадает и все отображается корректно.
Я написал касательно этой проблемы создателям темы, которую я использую для моего сайта.

Ответ был следующим:
You need to contact your hosting provider and tell them to enable your access origin, I think that the code that they need to add on your server is this:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
As you can see in the image below the issue is not coming from the theme but from your server, see the red lines:

После этого я обратился к хостингу и получил следующий ответ:
"Данный вопрос к хостингу не относится. Это ограничение на использование файлов со стороннего ресурса. Возникает ошибка у Вас потому что на стороннем ресурсе нету данного правила."

В .htaccess добавил следующий код (здесь отображается не полностью):

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Но ничего не произошло, проблема осталась. Дальше вычитал, что нужно включить модуль mod_headers. Обратился опять в хостинг, где сказали следующее:

"Для того чтоб директивы из файла .htaccess отрабатывали для всех запросов Вам необходимо исключить все расширения файлов из списка статических.
Учтите что в таком режиме работы нагрузка на хостинг-аккаунт немного возрастет.
Данный модуль включен и работает для всех сайтов. 
Запросы для файлов из списка статических не доходят до Apache(именно он обрабатывает файлы .htaccess и директивы из них) .
Все файлы, которые есть в списке статических будет отдавать nginx и такие запросы не дойдут до Apache.

И действительно, после удаления всех статических расширений проблема пропала и сайт начал отображаться корректно. Но возникает вопрос. Сильно ли возрастет "нагрузка" на сайт от таких действий ? В интернете пишут, что нужный модуль включается одной командой - a2enmod headers, но ребята из поддержки не захотели мне помогать с этим и предложили удалить расширения, что я и сделал. Есть смысл дальше гнуть свою линию с включением модуль через команду или удаление расширений тоже сгодится ?

Comment: О каких статических расширениях речь? Покажите код .htaccess до и после. И да - в чем конкретно проблема? В китайских символах по бокам или символу в меню?

Comment: Сайт ваш нашел. В меню значок не выводился, потому что не подгружался фонт Flaticon. А что за китайские символы по бокам - непонятно. Сейчас разметки под них нет.